# Why does Spring's JDBC Templates doesn't use the tables default value

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, jdbctemplate

I have a table in MYSQL and I am using JDBC Templates to do an insert into that table.

One of the columns has a default value, and I am not specifying it in the `Map<String, Object> parameters` map.

I am getting an exception `Column 'colName' cannot be null`.

Can anyone explain this please?

Thanks

**Edit: code **

> ```
> contactDetailsInsertTemplate = new SimpleJdbcInsert( dataSource ).withTableName("contactdetails").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("contactcode");
> Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
> Number newId = contactDetailsInsertTemplate.executeAndReturnKey(parameters);
> ```

Comment: Please show the code you are using.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to limit the columns specified in the SQL Insert.

See [SimpleJdbcInsert.usingColumns()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsert.html#usingColumns%28java.lang.String...%29)

If you don't do this, the SQL statement will need values for ALL columns and the default values cannot be used.

e.g. use

```
insert into mytable (col1, col2) values (val1, val2);
```

instead of

```
insert into mytable values (val1, val2);
```

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT INTO mytable (1,null)` is not the same as `INSERT INTO mytable (1)`.  The prior specifically inserts `null`, the later leaves the decision up to the DB (which would be the default value).  Spring JDBC is doing the former.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both your answers are correct but NickJ's answer is more accurate for the specific question. i wish i could accept both of you but i'll accept him and upvote you :).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is somewhere else: when I use `SimpleJdbcInsert` and pass a map of parameters to it, I simple expect to create insert statment only with parameters I provided. I have a NOT NULL column in the table with DEFAULT value and I don't want to specify it. I also don't want to explicitly put all column names in `usingColumns()` as I've just do it when creating a map of parameters! Why should I do it again? The problem is that `SimpleJdbcInsert` want's to be smarter and add all columns to insert statement which is not necessary. Why not create a statement only using columns provided with parameters map?

See: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/54209-simplejdbcinsert-and-columns-with-default-values

Answer (score 1):

You can add the columns which have a default value as parameters to `usingGeneratedKeyColumns()`.
Column names included as parameters of that method will be omitted from the generated `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP is supplying a MAP to the `SimpleJdbcInsert` .

This is what I did.

1. I made sure the MAP only has columns that I want inserted.
2. I extracted the Map keys and converted them into `String[]` like below

   ```
    Set<String> set = map.keySet();
    String[] columnNames = (String[]) map.keySet().toArray(new String[set.size()]);`
   ```
3. When initiating the `SimpleJdbcInsert` I passed in the columns I want to be used as below

   ```
    SimpleJdbcInsert sji = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("table_name");
    sji.usingColumns(columnNames);`
   ```

Hope it helps.